# Using self dot notation doesn't call dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notation

The dealloc method of my view controller class is not called when popped after being pushed with the following code:

```
    self.playerViewController = [[VideoPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self.playerViewController set_video:video];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.playerViewController animated:YES];

[self.playerViewController release];
```

However if I change the push code to the following, then my dealloc is called appropriately after the view controller is popped:

```
    playerViewController = [[VideoPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[playerViewController set_video:video];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:playerViewController animated:YES];

[playerViewController release];
```

I thought I understood the use of dot notation/self, but obviously not.  Can anyone explain the problem here?

Here is the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) VideoPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
```

and here is the synthesize:

```
@synthesize playerViewController;
```

Comment: Instead of [self.playerViewController release], it is  self.playerViewController = nil;  Note that this QA is hugely out of date, technology-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retaining twice.

```
self.playerViewController = [[VideoPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    ^ retain + 1                                        ^^^^^ retain + 1
```

But you only release one time.

To fix your memory management issue you could change the code to something like this:

```
self.playerViewController = [[[VideoPlayerViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

---

And many people say `[self.foo release]` is bad style. You should consider to replace it with `[foo release]`

Comment: I'd go beyond 'bad style' and say that `[self.foo release]` is an error. Assuming that `foo` is a retain property,  that line will release and potentially deallocate the object that `foo` points to, leaving self with a bad pointer in its foo property. Using `self.foo` at that point will cause a crash. Assigning a new value to `self.foo` will also cause a crash, since the setter will first try to release the (formerly) existing object.

Comment: Doh. Just remembered that we're talking about `-dealloc` here, so there's not much chance of anyone ever using `self.foo` after this point, but it still seems very wrong.